# How do I cross-compile libsndfile for Arm/Raspberry Pi

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, libsndfile, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a working cross-compiler running under Linux (Debian squeeze amd64) but I can't seem to link my files with the installed `libsndfile`, I'm assuming I need to cross-compile the source to target the Raspberry-Pi and link to that version. But I can't seem to find straightforward instructions on doing the `./configure` and `make` stage to compile to the target.

**Note:** I followed these steps: [How do I build a GCC 4.7 toolchain for cross-compiling?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1/85) to get the cross compiler built and using **Eclipse**.

Comment: What is the name of the cross-compiler? It should be <something>-gcc.

Comment: @ErikdeCastroLopo - Cheers for taking the time to answer, I'll warn you I'm a complete noob to this linux/cross-compilation stuff. The compiler is: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc built using the crosstools-ng tool.

Comment: Beware, I am seeing some issues with its configure script determining largefile support, and getting it wrong when building on a 64-bit host machine. Rename `AC_SYS_EXTRA_LARGEFILE` to `AC_SYS_LARGEFILE` in `configure.ac`, and then it seems to build properly on 64-bit hosts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, what you want to do is something which you probably cannot do within Eclipse.

Instead you need a terminal (eg xterm or gnome-terminal). The you need to run the configure script with something along the lines of:

`./configure --prefix=$HOME/Arm --build=i386-linux --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi`

Watch the configure output to make sure that the configure script picks up the correct compiler and then do:

`make && make install`

When you then want to build something else that links against the Arm binaries, make sure they get the headers from `$HOME/Arm/include` and link against the library in `$HOME/Arm/lib`.

You should be able to find lots of documentation about cross compiling stuff that uses autoconf generated configure scripts on the net.