# Compiling libsndfile for STM32F4xx Discovery Board

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, stm32f4discovery, libsndfile

I'm trying to cross-compile [libsndfile](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/) for the STM32F board. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576168/how-do-i-cross-compile-libsndfile-for-arm-raspberry-pi) SO question, but I'm having trouble in the configure step.

I have installed the cross-compiling tools with `apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi`.

I ran `./autogen.sh` then `export CC=arm-none-eabi-gcc` and `./configure --host=arm-none-eabi`. I have also tried other host options from the SO question mentioned above.

But configure returned:

```
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... arm-none-eabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/arun/build/libsndfile':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

config.log shows:

```
configure:4135: arm-none-eabi-gcc    conftest.c  >&5
 /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.9.3/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
/build/newlib-5zwpxE/newlib-2.2.0+git20150830.5a3d536/build/arm-none-eabi/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:70: 
undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This lead to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc) SO question so I manually edited configure and added `--specs=nosys.specs` to the ac_compile and ac_link variable. But I'm still seeing the error.

The author of libsndfile [suggested](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/issues/372#issuecomment-373610113) setting CFLAGS and LDFLAGS, but I'm not sure what to set them to.

Not sure what else to try at this point. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the configure problem by setting `export LDFLAGS="specs=nosys.specs"` before running `./configure --host=arm-none-eabi`